# ANTLR grammar from bison

Tags: antlr, grammar, bison

I'm trying to translate a grammar from bison to ANTLR. The grammar itself is pretty simple in bison but I cannot find a simple way for doing this.

Grammar in bison:

```
expr = expr or expr | expr and expr | (expr)
```

Any hints/links/pointers are welcome.

Thanks,
Iulian

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ANTLR3, you cannot create left recursive rules (ANTLR4 can handle left recursion in certain cases):

```
a : a b
  ;
```

tail recursion is fine:

```
a : b a
  ;
```

For more information on left recursive rules, see [ANTLR's Wiki](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Left-Recursion+Removal).

So, your example could look like:

```
parse
  :  expr+ EOF
  ;

expr
  :  orExpr
  ;

orExpr
  :  andExpr ('or' andExpr)*
  ;

andExpr
  :  atom ('and' atom)*
  ;

atom
  :  Boolean
  |  '(' expr ')'
  ;
  
Boolean
  :  'true'
  |  'false'
  ;
```

Here's a small demo in Java:

```
grammar BoolExp;

@members {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if(args.length != 1) {
      System.out.println("Usage:");
      System.out.println(" - Windows    : java -cp .;antlr-3.2.jar BoolExpParser \"EXPRESSION\"");
      System.out.println(" - *nix/MacOS : java -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar BoolExpParser \"EXPRESSION\"");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    ANTLRStringStream in = new ANTLRStringStream(args[0]);
    BoolExpLexer lexer = new BoolExpLexer(in);
    CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    BoolExpParser parser = new BoolExpParser(tokens);
    parser.parse();
  }
}

parse
  :  e=expr EOF {System.out.println($e.bool);}
  ;

expr returns [boolean bool]
  :  e=orExpr {$bool = $e.bool;}
  ;

orExpr returns [boolean bool]
  :  e1=andExpr       {$bool = $e1.bool;} 
     ('or' e2=andExpr {$bool = $bool || $e2.bool;}
     )*
  ;

andExpr returns [boolean bool]
  :  e1=atom        {$bool = $e1.bool;} 
     ('and' e2=atom {$bool = $bool && $e2.bool;}
     )*
  ;

atom returns [boolean bool]
  :  b=Boolean      {$bool = new Boolean($b.text).booleanValue();}
  |  '(' e=expr ')' {$bool = $e.bool;}
  ;

Boolean
  :  'true'
  |  'false'
  ;

Space
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r') {skip();}
  ;
```

First create a lexer & parser (1) and then compile all source files (2). Finally, execute the `BoolExpParser` class (3).

### 1

```
// Windows & *nix/MacOS
java -cp antlr-3.2.jar org.antlr.Tool BoolExp.g
```

### 2

```
// Windows
javac -cp .;antlr-3.2.jar *.java

// *nix/MacOS
javac -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar *.java
```

### 3

```
// Windows
java -cp .;antlr-3.2.jar BoolExpParser "false and true or true"

// *nix/MacOS
java -cp .:antlr-3.2.jar BoolExpParser "false and true or true"
```

[Terence Parr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/275496/terence-parr)'s [ANTLR reference](http://pragprog.com/titles/tpantlr/the-definitive-antlr-reference) is *the book* on ANTLR. And [Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12541/scott-stanchfield) created some excellent [video tutorials](http://javadude.com/articles/antlr3xtut/) on ANTLR 3 (with Eclipse).

Comment: Thanks a lot - it looks good to me. Can you suggest me a link/book where I can read more about this? EDIT: the link is fine; thanks again.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a link to the Wiki and a book recommendation. Good to hear it helped you.

Comment: antlr4 can handle direct left-recursion now