# Spurious nondeterminism warnings from antlr 2.7.6

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr2

I'm trying to create a simple expression parser with antlr 2.7.6 and am getting some nondeterminism warnings during compilation. The generated java source seems to work exactly as i want it, but I would like to know if its possible to suppress this warnings or if I'm doing something wrong in the grammar.

The parser is to be used in a project that already has a dependency on this old antlr version, so upgrading to 3.4 is probably not an option. The grammar itself look similar to the one in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2553403/139595).

Here is the output during compilation:

```
Using Antlr grammar: expr.g
ANTLR Parser Generator   Version 2.7.6 (2005-12-22)   1989-2005
expr.g:15: warning:nondeterminism upon
expr.g:15:     k==1:OR
expr.g:15:     between alt 1 and exit branch of block
expr.g:19: warning:nondeterminism upon
expr.g:19:     k==1:AND
expr.g:19:     between alt 1 and exit branch of block
```

And here is the simplified grammar exhibiting the problem:

```
header {
package net.jhorstmann.i18n.tools;

import net.jhorstmann.i18n.tools.*;
import net.jhorstmann.i18n.tools.expr.*;
}

class ExprParser extends Parser;

expression returns [Expression r = null]
    : r=or_expr
    ;

or_expr returns [Expression r = null] { Expression e = null; }
    : r=and_expr   (OR e=and_expr   { r = new OrExpression(r, e); })*
    ;

and_expr returns [Expression r = null] { Expression e = null; }
    : r=prim_expr  (AND e=prim_expr { r = new AndExpression(r, e); })*
    ;

prim_expr returns [Expression r = null] { Expression e = null; }
    : b:BOOL                   { r = new ConstantExpression(Integer.parseInt(b.getText())); }
    | NOT e=expression         { r = new NotExpression(e); }
    | OPEN e=expression CLOSE  { r = e; }
    ;

class ExprLexer extends Lexer;

options {
    k=2;
}

WS      : (' ' | '\t')+ { $setType(Token.SKIP); };
BOOL    : '0' | '1';
NOT     : '!';
OPEN    : '(';
CLOSE   : ')';
OR      : '|' '|';
AND     : '&' '&';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odd, ANTLR 3 has no problems with such a grammar.

Because its warning about an "exit branch of block", try *anchoring* your entry rule with an end-of-file token (`EOF`):

```
expression returns [Expression r = null]
    : r=or_expr EOF
    ;
```

### EDIT

I'd include an unary negate-expression like this:

```
expression
    : or_expr EOF
    ;

or_expr
    : and_expr (OR and_expr)*
    ;

and_expr
    : unary_expr (AND unary_expr)*
    ;

unary_expr
    : NOT prim_expr
    | prim_expr
    ;

prim_expr
    : BOOL
    | OPEN or_expr CLOSE
    ;
```

Comment: Thanks, adding `EOF` fixed the warning, if antlr is allowed to NOT consume all the input then I see where the nondeterminism is. Adding `options {greedy=true;}:` before the `OR` token also shut up the warning but your solution is much better. The colon seems to be required for assignments from lexer rules.

Comment: @JörnHorstmann, ah, I see, didn't know about the difference between `x:TERMINAL` and `y=production` in v2.7.

Comment: Hm, I spoke too soon, if I simply add the `EOF` then the expression `!(0)` won't be parsed anymore, if I change the rule to `NOT e=or_expr` the warnings return.